# How to dissolve magnesium malate in water?

Tags: water

When I mix magnesium citrate with hot water, it quickly dissolves and the water becomes transparent. When I do the same with magnesim malate, it does not dissolve,  it sinks to the bottom as sand. 
The question is how to dissolve the magnesium malate so that the water becomes transparent like with magnesium citrate?

Comment: The term you are looking for is "solubility".

Comment: According to this publication from the EFSA https://efsa.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.2903/j.efsa.2018.5292. Magnesium malate is freely soluble in water so if your material does not dissolve are you sure of its identity?

Comment: @Waylander I have tried couple of different brands and all behave the same.

Comment: @waylander [this MSDS](https://www.mineralsinc.com/MSDS/MagnesiumMalate_msds.htm) begs to differ on solubility.  Whassup?

Comment: I cannot reconcile the difference between the 2 sources but the OPs experience suggests yours is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't.  It's [insoluble in water](https://www.mineralsinc.com/MSDS/MagnesiumMalate_msds.htm).

Being a carboxylic acid salt, it may be introduced into the body by reaction with hydrochloric acid in gastric juice.

Similar data in magnesium citrate, shown [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.fishersci.com/store/msds%3FpartNumber%3DAA41954A7%26productDescription%3DMAG%2BCITRATE%2B2BSC%2BHYDRATE%2B5KG%26vendorId%3DVN00024248%26countryCode%3DUS%26language%3Den&ved=2ahUKEwjUlKmSw-znAhWUWc0KHYGNDeYQFjABegQIBhAB&usg=AOvVaw3D35sp4HixBNA2zD7rTxYV) for the dibasic salt $\ce{MgH(C6H5O7)}$, indicate more solubility for the citrate.  Possibly the citrate ion, with more oxygen atoms, can complex magnesium and other metal ions more efficiently through chelate formation.